# How do I delete empty strings in array

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I want to get `delete_if` to delete empty strings from an array. With the solution below, the array still contains many empty strings.

```
products = my_text.split(/\t+/)
products.delete_if {|element| element == " " || "" || element.nil?}
```

Is there anything missing?

Comment: `products.reject! { |s| s.strip.empty? || s.nil? }`

Comment: You'll want to change that to `products.reject! { |product| product.nil? || product.strip.empty? }` otherwise you'll try to `strip` `nil`

Comment: Not sure if I follow your change @Momer. Also nil values are what I'd like to delete as well. oldergod's solution seemed to have worked.

Comment: Weird, it should have raised an error. Basically, oldergod's block sent `strip` to `s` before evaluating whether or not `s` was `nil`. This should have raised `NoMethodError: undefined method 'strip' for nil:NilClass`. By reversing the order, you can avoid that situation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem with your code is explained by Ed S.
Otherwise, you can do

```
products.reject! { |s| s.nil? || s.strip.empty? }
```

Why do you need to test `nil?` first? Let's check few lines.

```
nil.strip
# NoMethodError: undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass
"   ".strip
# => ""
```

Now, with a different order, what the code does if the object is a string, and then if it is nil.

```
"  ".strip || "  ".nil?
# => ""
nil.strip || nil.nil?
# NoMethodError: undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass
# Oh you don't want that to happen, do you?
```

This means you don't want to call `strip.empty?` when your object is `nil`.
And as you know, when you have `a || b`, if a is truthy (i.e. not `nil` nor `false`), `b` will never be called.
You test first if the string is `nil` ; if it is, you don't need to check the right part (so you won't get a undefined method error) and the object will be removed from your products list.

Comment: As of Ruby 2.3, you can use the [safe navigation operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/) to avoid checking for `nil`: `products.reject! { |s| s&.strip&.empty? }`

Answer (score 4):

As per Rails 6.1, You can use `compact_blank`,
https://apidock.com/rails/v6.1.3.1/ActionController/Parameters/compact_blank

```rb
["a", "", " "].compact_blank
=> ["a"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Well this is wrong:

```
element == " " || "" || element.nil?
```

Should be

```
products = products.delete_if {|element| element == " " || element == "" || element.nil?
```

Note that you had a `|| "" ||` in there. You weren't comparing `element` to `""`, you were testing the "truthiness" of `""` (which evaluates to `true` btw, screwing up your empty string check).

This of course assumes your definition of an "empty string" is either nil, `" "`, or `""`.  What about

```
"  "
```

or even

```
"         "
```

?

Comment: That certainly got me on the right track! But now as I debug it, that line of code executes multiple times and by the time it's done it deletes the whole array. For some reason the boolean evaluates to true since each string has at least one space in it.

Comment: Yeah so you anticipated my problem with your answer edit haha.

Comment: @AdamBronfin: String comparison doesn't work that way.  It's not a `contains`, it's a comparison against the value, no more.  Use @oldergod's suggestion in the comments.

Comment: And my experience thus far has shown me I only am plagued with " ", the "" || nil was just out of paranoia. But I suppose I could just include a regex that identifies some continuation of white space and only space.

Answer (score 1):

[String#strip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-strip) each element then reject empty elements:

```rb
arr.map!(&:strip).reject!{|s| s.empty?}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm maybe a bit last here (where were you 6 years ago ?), but here is my suggestion,to handle `nil` , `""` and `" "`

`arr.compact.map(&:strip).reject(&:empty?)`

For example:
`["", nil, "toto", "  "].compact.map(&:strip).reject(&:empty?)`

`# => ["toto"]`

Happy Covid lock-down !

Answer (score 1):

So if you have an array of strings could easily remove empty values using `reject` function:

Having an array of string like this one:

`array = ["", "ABC", "DEF", ... , "", "ZXY"]`

If you use `reject`:

`array.reject(&:empty?)`

Will output a clean array of string:

`=> ["ABC", "DEF", "ZXY"]`